# Can I create a conda environment from multiple yaml files?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Is it possible to create a conda environment from two yaml files?

something like

> conda env create -f env1.yml -f env2.yml

or create a enviornment from one yaml file, then update the environment with the second yaml file?

> conda env create -f env1.yml
> conda env update -f env2.yml

Comment: have you tried any of the above?

Comment: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html

Comment: Both should work, but I would prefer the former. It is usually better to provide all requirements at creation, rather than mutate. Also, if you did the latter, I think it would require a `--name|-n` argument for the `update` stepp, otherwise it will update the currently active environment, which is not the one immediately created before.

Answer (score 2):

@sam is right, see relevant github issue:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9294

A potential work around is to use [conda-merge](https://github.com/amitbeka/conda-merge), with for example:

```
pip install conda-merge
conda-merge env1.yml env2.yml > env.yml
conda env create -f env.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Does not seem to work. `conda env create` only uses the final `--file` argument and ignores the others. `conda create` and `conda update` do not support yaml files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps:

- `conda env create -f env1.yml` (create the new environment)
- `conda env update --name env_name --file env2.yml --prune` (add the additional modules)